# Definition of angle as a difference between two derivatives

Tags: physical-chemistry

In the physical chemistry paper [De Gennes and Taupin - Microemulsions and the flexibility of oil/water interfaces](https://doi.org/10.1021/j100210a011), at some point the following definition of a squared angle is given (referred to as "angular correlations" and averaged using statistical mechanics):

$$\theta^2 = (\textbf{n}(0) - \textbf{n}(r))^2.$$

A little above in the text, the vector $\textbf{n}(x,y)$ is defined as:

$$\textbf{n}(x,y)= [-\partial z/ \partial x, -\partial z/ \partial y].$$

where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the cartesian coordinates and here z denotes the distance from a reference plane and is small.

However $\textbf{n}(r)$ is not explicitly defined (it seems that there is a change from cartesian to polar coordinates but I don't understand what it entails).

I am not familiar with such a definition of the angle. Moreover, the author carries on and at the end, $\theta$ actually is interpreted as an angle with a scalar value. How is this possible since the definition is a vectorial quantity and not a scalar? There is something that I don't understand here. There might be some notation I am not familiar with.

Physically, this seems to represent the angle between two normal vectors on an undulating interface (which undulates with respect to a perfect reference plane at z = 0)

Comment: They didn't change to polar coordinates, $r$ is the position vector, it's just a shorter way of writing $n(x,y)$ as $n(r)$. Also you should find a better way to link the paper as not everyone can gain access to this literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the normal vectors ${\bf n}(x,y)$ to the surface $z=z(x,y)$ should read
$$
{\bf n}= \frac{1} {\sqrt{1+ \left(\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+ \left(\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2}} \left(1, -\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},  -\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\\
\approx \left(1, -\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},  -\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}\right) 
$$
You omitted the rather impotant  $n_z\approx 1$ in their eq IV.4

As, with the correct formula,  the normal vectors ${\bf n}$ are normalized ${\bf n}\cdot {\bf n}=1$ we have
$$
({\bf n}(0)-{\bf n}(r))^2= {\bf n}(0)\cdot {\bf n}(0)+ {\bf n}(r)\cdot {\bf n}(r)- 2 {\bf n}(0)\cdot {\bf n}(r)\\= 1+1 - 2 \cos\theta=2-2(1-\theta^2/2+\ldots )\approx  \theta^2.
$$
Here $\theta$ is angle between ${\bf n}(0)$ and ${\bf n}(r)$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that we could use a square on vector as well to represent dot products. It does make sense to have this first order development in $cos \theta$. One more step that I finally understand in this mess!

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand any of what you just said here. This might be related to quantum electrodynamics, of which I have almost no knowledge.

Comment: @Glxblt76  It was an accidently duplicated  response to another question, Nothing to do with yours ! I thought I had deleted it.  I hope  it is gone now!